# A strange summation

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

> I sum up S4; there exists a ⵢ8

How many numbers does this strange summation encode, and what's the encoding?

**Hint:**

> You do the hokey pokey and you turn your head around

Comment: Is S4 referring to rot13(gur flzzrgevp tebhc bs qrterr sbhe be ba bs vgf vfbzbecuvfzf)?

Comment: @ThomasMarkov No, the puzzle is a lot simpler than that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Based on Thomas' answer and the hint on that, the answer is:

> 12345678

Because:

> 'I sum up S4' can be represented as 'I∑S4'
>  'There exists a ⵢ8' can be represented as '∃aⵢ8' ('a' thanks to hdsdv)
>  You turn your *head* around, as in the top half of the symbol.
>  'I' remains unchanged, and looks like a '1'
>  '∑' twists the top to look like 'Z', which also looks like '2'
>  'S' twists the top to looks like '3'
>  '4' remains unchanged
>  '∃' twists the top to look like a squared '5'
>  'a' twists the top to look like a '6'
>  'ⵢ' twists the top to look like '7'
>  '8' remains unchanged

Comment: Nice, i was thinking similar train

Comment: I think the missing digit is in there as well, encoded as rot13(n).

Comment: @hdsdv I think you are right, I was looking for that, but thought it would be a 'b'. Thanks!

Comment: Well done, and nice explanation!

Answer (score 3):

> A single number. "I∫S4;∃ⵢ8" looks like $1554.358$.

Comment: You're on the right track with rot13(gheavat jbeqf vagb flzobyf, ohg na nqqvgvbany genafsbezngvba arrqf gb or cresbezrq gb erirefr ratvarre gur bevtvany ahzoref.) Also, your choice for "sum up" is incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

> $I\sum S4\exists ⵢ8$ gives $1324328$

Because:

> Based on the hint, the symbols that are reversed forms of numbers need to be turned around, so the $\Sigma$ is reversed to a 3, the S is reverses to a two and the ⵢ is also reversed to a 2.

So,

> To answer the question, 5 of the seven digits in the "original number" (1324328) are encoded into letters and words.

Comment: This is incorrect. Perhaps you should compare my hint and the original - there's a significant difference.